# Hide position absolute element outside position relative parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'have a position relative parent element,

```
<div style="position:relative" id="a">
```

and inside that div I'm generating some position absolute elements with jQuery,

```
<div style="position:absolute;right:0" id="b">
```

those elements are animated with jQuery from right:0 to right:999 but I want that when the "b" div goes out of his parent hide or better remove this div

Comment: Question is missing the minimal code.. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask section "Help others reproduce the problem"

Comment: `overflow:hidden` on parent div ie, `#a`

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use overflow: hidden; for div a to hide div b

```
<div style="position:relative;overflow: hidden;" id="a">
```

Answer (score 0):

Set parent  to `overflow: hidden`.

Or you animate `"b"` element to `opacity: 0` when it reaches the edge.